# Wordpress: Use different loops

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm making an online magazine. Right now I'm trying to show the posts I'm posting. I've managed to do that, but what I want is that if a post is categorized in "Streetstyle", the loop will be completely different then if it's categorized in "Photography". I've mangaged to do this with one category, how can I do the same with other categories, and style it another way? I tried using the same code as `<?php if (is_category( 'Streetstyle' ) || in_category( 'Streetstyle' ) ) { ?>`, but then the theme just gets bugged and the posts shows up twice. Do you know of a better way to do this?

This is my code:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=9' . '&orderby=date'); 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>         
            <?php if (is_category( 'Streetstyle' ) || in_category( 'Streetstyle' ) ) { ?>
                <div <?php post_class('pin streetstyle'); ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="heading">
                <h1>Fashion</h1>
                </div>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                ?> 
                <div class="heading">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
                </a>
                </div>
             <?php } else { ?>   
                <div <?php post_class('pin'); ?>>
                <h1>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                the_content('Les mer <br><br>'); ?> 
                </div>
             <?php } ?>           
        <?php endwhile;
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Since it is a display issue, did you try to achieve this using css ? And you should use `pre_get_posts` hook instead of `query_posts`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of categories I would recommend using switch, it will save you time and your code will look a lot cleaner.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

I've slimmed this down a bit, but this is probably more what you're after

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=9' . '&orderby=date'); 
    while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
    <?php if(is_category('Streetstyle') || in_category('Streetstyle')) : ?>
        <div <?php post_class('pin streetstyle'); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="heading">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>   
        <div <?php post_class('pin'); ?>>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <?php 
                if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail();
                the_content('Les mer <br><br>');
            ?> 
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>           
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```